# can the mediaplayer output a wav file?

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

My code right now includes a mediarecorder that outputs a 3gp file into emulated storage. Is there any way to have the mediarecorder output a wav file instead? or maybe should I take the 3gp file and convert it to wav in the method?

```
package com.example.wesle.noisemachine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReceiveScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlay, buttonDecode;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    private String outputFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_screen);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonDecode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDecode);
        buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
        System.out.println(outputFile);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                    System.out.println("ISE Catch");
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("IO Catch");

                }
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();

                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("E Catch");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonDecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



            }
        });

        //Code for the back button
        Button backbuttonR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbuttonR);
        backbuttonR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ReceiveScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAV is a raw audio format that uses PCM encoding. `MediaRecorder` does not provide raw audio recording.

If you want to record WAV, use [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) instead.